# Calculate counts of unique values based on other column

Tags: python, pandas

First group with col1  then find the counts of unique item in col2, not the **number of counts**  `.value_counts` not giving desired results

```
 df
      col1 col2
    1 A      x  
    2 A      y
    3 A      x
    3 B      x
    4 B      x
    5 c      x
    6 c      y
    7 c      z
    
    desired output
    
    A 2
    B 1
    c 3
```

Comment: Try: `df.groupby('col1')['col2'].nunique()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `nunique`:

```
df.groupby('col1')['col2'].nunique()
```

Output:

```
col1
A    2
B    1
c    3
Name: col2, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df.groupby(["col1"])["col2"].nunique()
```